# How to hide text format options when using WYSIWIG module?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

Using [this tip](http://timonweb.com/how-remove-format-options-guideliness-comments-textarea-drupal-7) I was previously hiding the text format options with

```
$form['und'][0]['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

When I enabled WYSIWYG it wouldn't show the editor and I had to use

```
$form['und'][0]['format']['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
$form['und'][0]['format']['guidelines']['#access'] = FALSE; 
$form['und'][0]['format']['help']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

What's left now is this bottom box (below Path: p...)
[image]

This is the HTML that's generating it:

```
<fieldset class="filter-wrapper form-wrapper" id="edit-comment-body-und-0-format">
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper"><input id="edit-comment-body-und-0-format--2" class="wysiwyg wysiwyg-processed" type="hidden" name="comment_body[und][0][format]" value="filtered_html"></div>
</fieldset>
```

I could hide it with CSS. How would I hide it with code similar to above? Btw, I'm aware of Better Formats module but don't want to use it just for that.

Answer (score 3):

Try unsetting the field elements. According to the blog post this kills TinyMCE

```
<?php
  function [theme_name]_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
  {
    $form['comment_body']['#after_build'][] = 'remove_tips';
  }

  function remove_tips(&$form)
  {
    unset($form['und'][0]['format']['guidelines']);
    unset($form['und'][0]['format']['help']);
    return $form;
  }
?>
```

source: [technonaturalist](http://technonaturalist.net/blog/2011/08/drupal-7-notes-unsetting-formatting-tips)

Comment: thanks, but I need TinyMCE to render, just not the extra fieldset

Comment: Looks like the Better Formats module just sets the inline style property to display: none. It does reconstruct the whole filter widget into two parts which might be what preserves the WYSIWYG code through intercepting and altering `$type['text_format']['#process']` to pointing to its own process function copying mostly from the Drupal core `filter_process_format($element)`. Since most news editors I work with make a massive mess using WYSIWYG they now only get BUEditor which works will with removing the filter wrapper fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

There is also https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats, which allows to limit the formats per field.